# retrieving gravatar using jquery knockout js

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, knockout.js, md5

I am trying to get the gravatar of multiple uses to be displayed in one page and i am using a foreach loop for that. Also i am using knockout js to get the information like email and name and returned as json. Since i cannot use razor with gravatar because it requests a string to be passed in as an email and what i have are returned "data-bind="text:Email"

I am trying to use the MD5 concept and i am very new to this and not sure if i am following the right steps. I found this online from google code: http://www.devcurry.com/2012/06/retrieving-gravatar-using-jquery.html

and i tried to implement but not sure if my code is properly written:

**Part of my javascript related to what i am doing:**

```
$.views.Games.UserViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
    self.Email = ko.observable(data.Email);

    self.Hash = CryptoJS.MD5(Email);
};
```

**My View Page:**

```
<img alt="Gravatar" title="My Gravatar" data-bind="attr:{href:'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' +Hash()+'?s=30&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=G'}" />
```

With this i am not getting a gravatar to show. Any helpful information or tips is greatly appreciated.

**Code update**

I altered so this is how it looks:

**view model**
 `public string MD5Email { get{ return Email.MD5Hash(); } }`

**javascript**
`self.MD5Email = ko.observable('http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' + data.MD5Email + '?s=30&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=G');`

**view page**
`<img width="158" height="158" alt="Gravatar" data-bind="attr:{'src':MD5Email()}"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't put JS logic in your data-binds. Use a computed instead:

```
self.GravatarUrl = computed(function() {
    return 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' + self.Hash() + 's=30&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=G';
});
```

Second, your `Hash` needs to be a computed observable as well. The way you have it now, it's only evaluated once, when the JS first runs, and when most likely `Email` is null. So your Gravatar URL is never being populated with a valid email hash.

```
self.Hash = computed(function() {
    return CryptoJS.MD5(self.Email);
});
```

However, since this `Hash` computed is only being used to serve the other computed at this point, you can and should probably just combine the two:

```
self.GravatarUrl = computed(function() {
    var hash = CryptoJS.MD5(self.Email);
    return 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' + hash + 's=30&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=G';
});
```

Then, your data-bind becomes simply:

```
<img alt="Gravatar" title="My Gravatar" data-bind="attr:{ href: GravatarUrl }" />
```

Much cleaner.

**UPDATE based on OP's update**

I'm not sure why you changed the logic of the code I gave you, but that's why it's not working.

First, it seems you've given up on MD5 in Javascript and added it to your view model. That's fine, but you've introduced the same logic problem you had earlier by setting the `self.MD5Email` to the entire URL based on `data.Email`. This is not a computed and data.Email is not an observable. It exists only at the initial creation of the KO view model. What you should be doing is something like:

```
self.MD5Email = ko.observable(data.MD5Email);

self.Gravatar = ko.computed(function () {
    return 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' + self.MD5Email() + '?s=30&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=G'
});
```

You've rightly corrected setting the img src instead of href (I missed that too), but using the parenthesis is unnecessary when you're not doing other JS logic at the same time, so it should just be:

```
data-bind="attr: { src: Gravatar }"
```

Comment: This looks great! i am trying it and not sure if maybe the md5.js is not running properly or not but with this i am getting a single empty gravatar. I will play around and see what i could come up with

Comment: I updated my code and currently i am still getting one image for all users and not sure what could be going wrong.

Comment: fixed to your updates and now i am getting an empty rectangle - i wasn't sure i was to have a `return` in for the `self.Gravatar` but when i added the `return` i am getting the the gravatar logo symbole for all users.

Comment: just realized that the image returned in display is the same as in the first part of the return `http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/` and it is not taking in anything after the `+`

Comment: Sorry. Forgot the return. Fixed now. You know, it's entirely possible that there actually isn't an image for all the users. They have to have given Gravatar something to use at some point. It's not just magic. I would suggest trying manually and see if you actually should be getting some other image in the first place. In otherwords. Take one of the email addresses. Go MD5 it somewhere (there's sites online that will do that for you), and then construct the URL yourself and see what happens. If you still get the default Gravatar pic, that's just it.

Comment: ok i will try that - but if the user doesn't have a gravatar shouldn't it generate one of the random looking gravatars like the one i have with my name here on this site? Or is it because of the way the return is constructed. Thank you sooo much for all your help i will be marking this as answered after i test the md5

Comment: Gravatar actually lets you specify what the "default" image should be. It's got a few options to choose from and you can even specify your own. You might want to look at their developer documentation at bit: http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/#default-image

Comment: yes - i used `GravatarHelper.DefaultImageIdenticon` in a razor html tag for the gravatar but i thought in the return there is `d=identicon` but will look into that

Comment: Figured it out. The hash is case sensitive so i had to convert all emails to lower case and then i had to remove the hard coded `amp;` from the url. Thanks for all your help and useful tips.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps but I wrote a binding to do just this recently:

https://github.com/grofit/knockout.gravatar

So you can just use it using the knockout binding goodness.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! will def. look into trying it out.